# what is the opposite of has_many in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering if there is a way to have a Book belong to many Authors in rails. I know that I would have the has_many in the Authors model but how would I have the book point back to many authors? I assume that belongs_to doesn't work if it belongs to many instances of the same class.

Comment: [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)?

Comment: You generally use a join table for this.

Comment: You are describing a many-to-many relationship. A book has many authors...an author can have many books. `has_and_belongs_to_many` used to be the way to go...now you should use [has_many :through](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)